# wxPython SetLayoutDirection Doesn't Work On Mac

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

On Windows with wxPython 3.0.2 SetLayoutDirection works as expected in htmlWindow. SetLayoutDirection(2) will allow me to display RTL texts. However, with the same version on Mac it does not work. It is always the default LTR text flow. Plus GetLayoutDirection always returns 0 even after SetLayoutDirection(2) is supposedly set.

Was this feature missed on the Mac build? Is there a fix or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid RTL support simply is not implemented under Mac. I'll update the documentation to at least mention this for now, but this is all I can do.

Comment: That's unfortunate...well at least it works on Windows. Thanks for the notice.